# ubuntu 14.04 showing internal error

Tags: 14.04

I am using Lenovo B460E. I installed Ubuntu 14.04, and when I log in it is showing an error message 'Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error'. I reported many times but the Window is constantly appearing. Also, when I try to shutdown it gets stuck on the Ubuntu logo.

Comment: please elaborate 'Stuck on ubuntu logo'.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when Ubuntu 14 just came out but after updating these problems disappeared.

You have to look in the details of the popup to see which program is causing the error. This is very important to know what is going on. The popups may come from different packages. Based on that info, you may also find more information in your /var/log folder or find more information on the issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

Once you report the issue, the necessary data is sent for review and will be fixed in a later update.